# Jenkins failed to launch maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

The local maven runs fine. However Jenkins fails to launch it. I noticed the following in inverted slashes but not sure where it is coming from:

```
C:\TES\apache-maven-3.2.5-bin\apache-maven-3.2.5***/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main***
```

---

> $ java -cp
>   C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.5.jar;C:\TES\apache-maven-3.2.5-bin\apache-maven-3.2.5\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\TES\apache-maven-3.2.5-bin\apache-maven-3.2.5/conf/logging
>   jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main
>   C:\TES\apache-maven-3.2.5-bin\apache-maven-3.2.5\ "C:\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\jenkins\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.49.jar"
>   C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar
>   C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar
>   3411
>       ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = -1073741502
>       Finished: FAILURE

Comment: In Jenkins there is a Maven 3.1.X embedded whereas you are trying to start Maven 3.2.X where some changes have been in there. I assume you are using the Maven Job Type. You need to change to a freestyle job and call Maven directly.

Comment: That is no good either.

$ C:\TES\apache-maven-3.2.5-bin\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin\mvn.bat clean install
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined MAVEN_HOME in your Jenkins Master configuration? If not please do the same and it should work.